# cmake can't find gtest 1.8 in ubuntu 18.10

Tags: ubuntu, cmake, googletest

I am trying to run cmake on my project that used to work pretty well on Mac.

In my CMakeLists.txt I have:

`find_package(gtest REQUIRED CONFIG)`

When I run cmake I see:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:123 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "gtest" with any of
  the following names:

    gtestConfig.cmake
    gtest-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "gtest" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "gtest_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "gtest"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

I have built the sources in `/usr/include/gtest` and installed them into `/usr/lib/`.

Comment: The script which locates GTest is named [FindGTest.cmake](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.6/module/FindGTest.html), so you need to search the package "GTest", not "gtest".

Comment: Thanks, that worked!

Comment: @Tsyvarev Maybe put int an answer, so I can accept?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When call `find_package`, name of the package is **case-sensitive**. Correct name of the package, corresponded to GTest, is "GTest".

---

A package name with incorrect case may work sometimes (e.g. with *case-insensitive* filesystem, or if the package is described by `<lower-case-name>-config.cmake` file). But it is better to not rely on such features, and use a package name which is noted in its documentation.

Comment: @KansaiRobot: What do you mean by "does not work"? Even with proper `find_package(GTest REQUIRED)` you still got the error message "Could not find a package configuration file ..."? Or what?

Comment: I changed gtest for GTest in find_package. I still got the error in the original question.

Comment: So the error message starts with words `Could not find a package configuration file provided by "GTest"` in that **exact case**, doesn't it? Which CMake version do you use?

Comment: Yes. I am using 3.16.3

Comment: Strange, CMake 3.16.3 is shipped with script [FindGTest.cmake](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.16/module/FindGTest.html), so this script should be found by `find_package(GTest)` call. Could you prepare your own question post, with exact error message you got and other information?

Comment: I did  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64968933/fail-to-find-gtest-inside-a-container

Comment: According to your question post, you could successfully use gtest from the simple project, but has a problem when use gtest under ROS/Catkin. That problem is absolutely **unrelated** with my answer and the question I have answered...